# Compiling .hx code directly (or indirectly) to a dynamic library (ndll)

Tags: dll, haxe, dynamic-library

I am working on a project and I have a plan to separate certain sections out into separate dlls/ndlls in the final program. The main reason I want to do this is to support plugins and add ons, so more functionality can be added if needed, but the core app can still be used if that's the only requirement.

I have done something similar in C# (abet through an IDE so I never had to write any linker/compiling commands) so I know the general process but I can't seem to find a way to write HX code and then have it compile into a ndll.

I found this http://old.haxe.org/doc/cpp/ffi?lang=en which shows how to compile cpp code into a ndll using hxcpp and g++. I would think there should be a way I can use LIME or HXCPP to create a build file that will allow me to do it in one step instead of having to make a "fake" main function to compile the HX to CPP or CS.

If anyone knows of a project that does this and has a build.hxml or build.xml file that describes this or a tutorial or guide that takes about this, I would love it see it.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to work your way out for yourself on this one. The URL you find seems like a good start though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
lime create extension TestExt
lime rebuild TestExt windows
```

Replace "windows" with "mac" or "linux" as appropriate. Assuming it works, the ndll will show up in a subfolder of `TestExt/ndll/`.

---

As for tutorials, I wrote [this one](http://player03.com/2014/08/09/openfl-extensions/). It's targeted at OpenFL programmers, but the "Writing code for iOS" section covers what you'll need to know. (You can also just model your code on the [template](https://github.com/openfl/lime/tree/master/templates/extension).)

In case it helps, I've made [a tool](https://github.com/player-03/ExtensionBoilerplate) to generate some of the boilerplate code that Lime requires.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to stay 100% Haxe but that doesn't look like it would work. Your guide makes it easy to setup and build, and I managed to get the template working in a few minutes.

Comment: Supposedly the OpenFL team figured out a way to write code in Haxe that previously had to be written in C++. They just haven't explained how.